# Drink 7 to 10 days after opening?

Tags: meaning, phrases, ambiguity, time

Is this label telling the consumer that it is best to consume the drink 7 to 10 days after opening it?

[image: Picture of juice carton label]

I know what they are getting at, but I feel like it should say "Best if consumed within 7 to 10 days **of** opening". Is my suspicion correct?

**This is what I perceive like the label is *really* saying**

```
    |----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
   (Opened)                        (Best consumed here)
```

Comment: No, it means you -don't- want to consume it -after- ten days, and may even be bad as early as 7 days.

Comment: Instead of saying "within 7 to 10 days of opening", why not just "within 10 days of opening"? Strange construction of sentence.

Comment: What it says is that if you consume it *before* Day 7, it will not be at its best.

Comment: @Mitch I know what they are trying to get at, and I understand the concept, but it seems like this sentence can be taken to mean something else

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah, I feel that the way the sentence is structured that it can be taken that way!

Comment: @Mohit I noticed that, too. Quite weird...

Comment: It doesn't mean that it will be *bad* after 7 days (although it might be bad after 10 days). It just means it won't be its best.

Comment: This is about taste, not safety.

Comment: (IMHO) Here's why it's written that way . . . you could have it sitting in your refrigerator for 2 weeks which is longer than 7-10 days - but probably protected by the packaging, somewhat, from spoiling.  So on day 15 of owning the product, you open the package.  ***Now*** you have 7-10 days to consume it while it's "best".  (Oh yeah, and "of opening" may not be clear to some people like saying "quarter of 4" for the time - what's the "of" mean?  But readers *should* know what "after opening" means.)

Comment: As aptly demonstrated by the comments above, the *only* thing this really says is "do not waste time on making sense of our instructions; we certainly didn't".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You are wilfully parsing it as though  "7 - 10 day" is an interval to which *within* applies. But *within* does not take an implicit interval like that. You could say "within the period 7 - 10 days", but that's the only way I can see to get the meaning you want.

Which leaves the alternative (and clearly intended) parsing *within x days after opening*, where x is specified loosely.

Answer (score 4):

The "Within" portion of the phrase is intended to eliminate the interpretation that you are trying to impose on it.

```
opened
0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---10
(within 7 days .............)    
(within 10 days .........................)
(within 7-10 days ..........?????????????)
```

The extended portion of the range covered by `.` is definitely good; the portion covered by `?` is probably good, but not guaranteed.

The "after opening" is probably there to frustrate the pedants who would insist that "within 7-10 days of opening" includes a total of 14-20 days:

```
                               open
10--9--8--7--6--5--4--3--2--1--0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9--10
          (within 7 days of ........................)
                               (within 7 days after )
```